# Convert list of object to CSV string

Tags: apex, soql, lightning-web-components, csv, d3

I'm using the d3 library trying to do a geo chart with LWC. To do so I need a csv file with my values in it like the example bellow

```
var promises = [];
promises.push(d3.json('d3js/map-population/regions.json'));
promises.push(d3.csv("d3js/map-population/population.csv"));
```

My JSON is already a static ressource in my org but for the CSV it will be the result of a SOQL query with my values. Something like that :

```
List<Account> listAcc = [SELECT City, CityCode__c, Value1__c, Value2__c FROM Account]
```

I tried creating a list of String adding the value of my list of Account but the result isn't what I was expected. The CSV file should looks like this :

```
CODE_REG, Name_REG, CODE_State, Name_State, Value1, Value2
my values seperated by coma
```

How can I do the trick without exporting a CSV file each time I want to retrieve my data through my lwc component implementing d3 library ?

Comment: IMO It would be ideal to use the list of objects. or whatever the JSON structure accepted by Geo charts instead of creating csv files.

Comment: There's a JSON and a CSV used by Geo charts. I already have the JSON of the chart I downloaded from web. Now I need to create a String accepted by d3 in a CSV format with the data from Salesforce, and I don't really know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend just using [papaparse](https://www.papaparse.com/). Once imported, you can have the list of objects returned from the wire call and passed directly into Papaparse, which will output a CSV for you.

```
let csv = Papa.unparse(accountData);
```

Since you're already using D3, I presume you're familiar with importing scripts to LWC. All you need is a bit of help, and that library can do it pretty easy.